# How can I automatically call an ASP.NET Core endpoint each X hours?

Tags: c#

I've build an API with ASP.NET Core. Some of my controllers have an endpoint, which need to run each X hours. Nevertheless I still want to be able to call the endpoint by my own at any time.

The endpoints all have the same structure:

```
[RequireHttps, HttpGet("/generate")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateFiles()
{
    // do stuff 
}
```

Does anybody know how I could achieve this in ASP.NET Core itself without any third-party tool? I thought of using a timer, but I feel like this is not the best way to do so. I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers! :)

Comment: Have a look at [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). That's what we're are using to do exactly the same.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride That looks awesome - Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: You are not giving a lot specifics here. If you want your code to be triggered every 8 hours, you need to run it every eight hours. Task Scheduler with a curl call is a very simple way. Consider, though, whether it might be better to put the code into a library and then run this as a job rather than via an endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

With [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) that's quite easy to do:

Inside the Program.cs/Startup.cs:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddHangfire(opts => opts
        .UseSqlServerStorage(config
            .GetSection(nameof(HangfireConfig))
            .Get<HangfireConfig>()
            .ConnectionString)
        .AddUpdateJob(builder.Environment))
    .AddHangfireServer()
```

And `AddUpdateJob()` is implemented like this:

```cs
public static IGlobalConfiguration AddUpdateJob(
    this IGlobalConfiguration opts,
    IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (!env.IsEnvironment("Local"))
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IMasterDataUpdater>(
            "masterdata-update",
            x => x.Update(),
            Cron.Hourly);
    }

    return otps;
}
```